# How do I move between splits in vim on startup?

Tags: bash, vim, vi

I would like to open up *netrw* by default when editing a file, then go to edit mode within the file:

```
gvim -c "Vexplore" -c "startinsert" "$fileName"
```

Unfortunately, the cursor will be in the *netrw* tree, so I'd need to do a `<C-w>L`, but cannot figure out how ot do do that with the `-c` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, you want `<C-w>l` ("move cursor to window on the right"), here, not `<C-w>L` ("move window to the far right").

"`-c` commands" are actually Ex commands so you can use the Ex command equivalent of `<C-w>l`, `:wincmd l`:

```
gvim -c Vexplore -c "wincmd l" -c startinsert "$fileName"
```

Note that the side on which `:Vexplore` opens a new window can be configured so "left" and "right" might not be super foolproof. These are better alternatives:

```
wincmd w
wincdm p
```

See `:help :wincmd` as well as `:help window-move-cursor`.